# J string manipulation using only builtins

Tags: j

You are given a string like `))()(())(`, and you wish to remove all instances of `()` from the string, which in this case means these two instances:

```
))()(())(
  ^^ ^^
```

leaving only `))()(`.

I know you can use the library function [stringreplace](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/user/lib_strings.htm#stringreplace), or you could load up a regex library, but I want to know is if there is a concise way of accomplishing this the the J builtin operators exclusively?

I should clarify that my own solution was:

```
#~(-.@+._1&|.)@('()'&E.)
```

which I consider verbose -- so any similar solutions would not qualify as "concise" in my book.  I'm really asking if there is a way to use a builtin (or maybe a simple combination of 2) to solve this directly.  I expect this answer is no.

Comment: There's a million ways to do this, here's one: `'()' (] {~ [: <^:3@, i.@#@[ +/ I.@:E.) '))()(())('`. But bear in mind J is biased towards *regular*, orthotopic data structures, where all elements are equal citizens. Strings usually don't fall into that category. J is more designed for the quantitative and mathematical; more like Matlab, less like Perl.

Comment: @DanBron Thanks, interesting perspective.  The fundamental problem here, though, extends beyond strings.  Eg, say I have a list of numbers, and I wish to remove all subsequences that match `2 3`.  Doesn't J struggle equally with this?  Btw I googled the intriguing term "orthotopic data structure" but didn't find anything CS related.

Comment: If you're removing some elements along an axis but leaving others, then you're not treating all elements like equal citizens. If you're dealing with "substrings", the issues I highlighted above apply whether those "substrings" are characters, numbers, boxes, or angry giraffes. By "orthotopic", I mean "rectangular", but [in the N-dimensional sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperrectangle). That is, all items have the same number of elements. There are no "ragged" arrays (in J, we deal with "ragged" arrays by hiding them inside boxes, thus making them regular/orthotopic again).

Comment: @DanBron Ok, understood.  This all sounds correct to me.  And please feel free to add your explanation with an answer of "no" and I'll accept it.  That said, I still find it disappointing that an "array language," to say nothing of a language with J's power, lacks the ability to easily remove list subsequences.  I mean, first sentence on the homepage: "J (J language) is a high-level, **general-purpose**, high-performance programming language."

Comment: I think once you get into the groove of J, you'll have a different understanding of what "array" means. In J, structure (shape) as *as much meaning* as value. An element's index is as important as its value. Like in in the integer `944121`; the position carries semantics. And like with that integer, you are much more likely to want to do things like `10 * 944121` than "remove all repeated digits", resulting in `9121`, because that *completely changes the identity of the object you're dealing with*. J is general purpose (Turing-complete), but like all langs, it niches where it shines.

Comment: Makes sense.  I've been using it for golfing and solving assorted puzzles (like project euler ones).  Sometimes the J solution is incredibly natural and terse.  Other times I feel like I'm bending it grotesquely to accomplish the simplest things (as here) . I assumed the fault was mine, that experts would always produce elegant solutions.  You're saying that is simply not the case.  There will be whole classes of problems for which J isn't particularly well suited?

Comment: Yes: even more, I make the claim that that is true for *all* languages, programming or natural or otherwise. There's even a [theorem proving there's no free lunch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_in_search_and_optimization). A Turing machine can solve *any* computable problem, but some classes of problems will be better addressable by certain methods (algorithms) and some will be better addressed by others, and there is no "one algorithm to rule them all". You won't find the "perfect language"; you'll only find "the perfect marriage" (between problem and solution).

Comment: To be clear, in your application of NFLT, something like "programming puzzles" is the problem space, languages are the solution space, and the cost function is something like the shortest solution in the language, or least complex (by some well-defined measure), etc?  Imo the practical and theoretical diverge here... as a matter of lived experience, some languages _are_ more powerful than others across a broad spectrum of problems (i'd even venture something like "all problems of likely interest").  And in this 
 case, J _could have_ included library functions as additional builtins

Comment: Yes, you hit it on the head.  Personally, I'm not a fan of "lived experience" being used as a counterpoint to "anecdotes are not data", but your point about the delta between theory and practice is well-taken. My own lived experience *is* that J is very powerful across a broad range of problems, but then I'm a corner case: I made my living off it for a handful of years, and persisted in being a fanboy for about a decade thereafter. But in re "library functions": isn't that specifically what you said you *didn't* want to use in this case, like `stringreplace`? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Also, you might be interested in checking out the [J category on RosettaCode](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:J). There you can see contributions on a wide range of applications from many different Jers, myself included. It should give you a lay of the land as to what problems J dominates and where it lags.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with your philosophical point.  At the same time I think it makes perfect sense to talk about a language's power, and to critique its design decisions, without a crisply defined problem space.  The implicit problem space is "the kinds of problems programmers solve."  I'll grant you if you press this point, you can break it down, but there's a hand-wavy element of "c'mon, we know what we're talking about" that _does_ have value as a heuristic.  re: `stringreplace` function, I meant J could have included a two character builtin that would more or less solve those problems.  (contd)

Comment: That they didn't I see as a kind of flaw.  It seems too fundamental a thing to relegate to library functions, if your intention it to build a general purpose language -- but don't get me wrong, I'm in awe of the language's design in general.  I'm also curious to hear why you're no longer a fanboy, if that was your implication?  And what languages you like best now?  And ty for those links.

Comment: For the most part we are completely on the same wavelength. I agree that we can compare languages more or less in the abstract. I think J has some advantages in the abstract and some disadvantages in the abstract. Even at the height of my fanboyhood I was never a Utopian. That doesn't fit my general mindset. In re fanboyhood, don't get me wrong, I am still a big *fan*, but when I said *fanboy* I meant it. I just don't spend as much time with J or programming in general as I used to. J is still my primary language, when I need it, though Perl6 has caught my attention recently.

Comment: Out of curiosity, Jonah, do you think that if this had a two character builtin that you'd run into another string processing problem tomorrow that was also too verbose, or do you consider removing occurrences of an array from another array to be fundamental in a way that others aren't? (Any of these for example: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.0/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html )

Comment: @dukereg, yes, i consider this one to be especially basic, in the "Easy things should be easy, and hard things should be possible" sense.  I understand that no matter what your set of primitives are, some problems will be difficult.  But I have a sense -- based on experience in multiple languages -- about which things I should fairly expect to be easy in a general purpose programming language, and this one qualifies for me.

Comment: @dan I agree with @Jonah, a primitive similar to `E.`:  "match with length" would have helped me immensely many times. It would work like this `'co' E: 'cocoa'`  ->  `11110`. OP, then, is trivial: `s #~ -. t E: s`.

Comment: @Eelvex I'll tell you a secret. I thought the same as you guys when I first started learning J. In fact, an "E with length" function is one of the very first things I ever put in [my personal utility script](http://www.jsoftware.com/svn/DanBron/trunk/config/startup.yes.ijs) (search for "Like E., this creates a boolean list"). I'll tell you another secret: despite that function being in there for more than 15 years now, I have *almost never used it*. Because once I started thinking "in J", changing the lengths of lists just kinda stopped occurring to me.

Comment: Here's a longer write-up I did once of [the experience of thinking "in J"](http://www.jsoftware.com/pipermail/programming/2013-January/030927.html), and how that effects the way you think about and treat data shape. It's as fundamental as data value.

Comment: @Dan I am no expert, but wouldn't what you've said just imply the need for J to have a primitive to turn heterogeneous arrays into homogeneous arrays of boxes?  It seems like that would be consistent with the philosophy you list, and would expand the range of problems J is elegant at solving.  You could use it with E. for this sort of problem, with 1 0 1 0 ... for arrays of "pairs" and so forth.  What am I missing?

Comment: @dukereg J does have such primitives. The most obvious is `<` (box). I think people have this view that J can't solve the kinds of problems described here. It can, has, does, and will. It just doesn't do it under OP's constraints ("a two character primitive which takes subsequences, no library functions allowed"). But also J is principally suited to numerical and mathematical processing. String processing is not its core strength. It even outsources regex to PCRE.

Comment: @DanBron Thanks for posting that link.  I think you and I share a similar interest in meta-level concerns about programming languages -- how they influence thought and their connection to natural language, among others.  I'd love to ask you some other questions that don't really fit the SO format.  Do you still read the J mailing list?  I also took the time to understand your solution.  It's quite beautiful and I see pure idiomatic J -- I'd forgotten about complementary selectors

Comment: @dan The obvious verbs like `<` and `;` don't turn heterogeneous arrays into arrays of boxes based on a meaningful interpretation of the subgroupings, they just put whole arrays in boxes.  While I agree that string processing _is not_ J's core strength, I just don't see why it _should not_ be.  What is it about these problems that prevents translation into J without such long sentences? Wouldn't it make sense to have a streamlined process to concisely transform data to J's way of thinking for processing?

Comment: @dukereg One way or another, when you put things in boxes, you are invoking `<`, on the surface or under the covers. Yes, applied directly to a noun, `<` puts the whole thing in a box, because it hs unbound rank. But it can be applied to smaller parts, either regularly (as with `<"0`) or based on patterns (like partitioning with `<;.1`, which is how `stringreplace`, `cut`, work under the covers). But selecting the pieces to box isn't `<`'s job: jamming its  input, whatever it is, into a box is. In re: *should not be*, I covered that briefly in my prior comments. String processing isn't J's aim

Comment: @Jonah Thank you! I don't follow the J Forums any more, but if you post a Q there and ping me a link here (anywhere on SE), I'll find a way to respond. My main issue is I no longer have a decorated email account to subscribe to the J Forums, and setting one up in my current environment is a bit of a PITA.

Comment: @DanBron, Thanks for the offer.  I will get my account activated and try that.  Related to the email decoration problem, check out 33mail.  I have no affiliation but I like them, it works exactly how I want it to, and they're cheap.

Comment: @Jonah Awesome! I'll check them out. Thank you for the recommendation. (BTW, I intended to type *dedicated email* address, but autocorrect and I have beef).

Answer (score 3):

I think you are right that there is no ultra-concise way of expressing the operation you want to perform using just J primitives. The version I came up was very much like the one Dan, suggested above. 
However given that a built in library verb `rplc` (based on `stringreplace`) performs exactly the operation you are after, I'm not sure why it would be better to replace it with a primitive.

```
   '))()(())(' rplc '()';''
))()(
```

Having said that, if you can come up with a [compelling case](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/System/Interpreter/Requests), then there is probably no reason it couldn't be added.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how concise it is, but I think that this will work:

```
   deparen=. (-.@:(+/)@:(_1&|. ,: ])@:E. # ]) 
   '()' deparen '))()(())('
))()(
```

Essentially the work is done by `-. @: (+/) @: (_1&|. ,: ] )@:E`. to create a bit string that removes the `'()'` instances using `#` (Copy) on the right argument.

`E.` identifies the positions of `'()'` using a bit string. Shift and laminate to get positions of `'('` and `')'`, add them together to have `1 1` in the string where ever there is a `'()'` and then negate so these positions become `0 0` and are removed using Copy

Comment: thanks, but i should have been more clear: i know it can be done, but i was hoping for something much more straightforward.  it seems incredibly odd to me that J, which is typically so powerful, has so much trouble with this simple task.